# Object must implement IConvertible Exception, when using dapper with .net core

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, dapper

I am using asp net core in my project with dapper ORM and Postgresql as database. I want to check if a user with a particular UUID (GUID in C#) value exists in the database or not. Following is my code to check the same:

```
public async Task<bool> DoesRecordExistAsync(Guid columnValue)
{

    bool doesRecordExist;

    doesRecordExist = await _connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<bool>("SELECT * FROM employee_master WHERE employee_id = @columnValue;", new { columnValue });

    return doesRecordExist;
}
```

Note: _connection is IDbconnection instance.

When executing the statement, I am getting the below error:

> Object must implement IConvertible.

Is there anything wrong with the above code.

Comment: Why would you assume that query could be converted to a `bool`? I assume you would want to do a `SELECT COUNT(*)...` instead and convert that to an `int`. Then return `true` if the int value is greater than zero.

Comment: ExecuteScalarAsync() will select a single value. If the converted type is specified as bool, it will return bool value depending on whether such a record exists or not. Same as Any() in LINQ.

Comment: How do you expect Dapper to convert an entire record to a `bool` though?

Comment: Nope. `ExecuteScalar` (and its async variant) will select the first column of the first row. This type may vary. Do not use `SELECT *` in general, and definitely not when combined with `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: @DavidG reference is taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006512/check-if-record-exists-with-dapper-orm

Comment: so what should I use to check if the record exists or not? @JeroenMostert

Comment: Yes, but see that query has a `COUNT` component...

Comment: @DavidG yes, it was my bad. But it was working when the database table does not contain UUID. Don't know why

Comment: Because a UUID cannot be converted into a boolean value. An integer ID can be converted though.

Comment: @DavidG but I was writing [select *], that means the whole table was converted to bool and when the table contains UUID, it causes the problem. Is there any specific reason that only due to UUID whole conversion was hampered?

Comment: No, the whole table isn't converted, only the first value of the first row. So if that first value was the ID column, it would use that.

Comment: ok, got your point. Thank You. @DavidG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query "`SELECT * FROM ....`" is returning matching **rows** from database; NOT the `bool` that you are expecting. The `ExecuteScalar` will return first column of first row. One cannot guarantee that *that* column is always a Boolean; and basically, you are not expecting value of that column either.

The query should be something like `select exists(select 1 from...` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7471625/5779732).
It will return `true`/`false` which you can then handle with `await _connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<bool>(......`.
So, the new code becomes:

```
bool exists = await _connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<bool>("select exists(select 1 from....");
return exists;
```

Alternatively (**slow**; not recommended), you should change your query to something `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` to get the count of records. Read more about optimization [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7943233/5779732).
Then you can cast it to `bool` something like below:

```
int count = await _connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM..........");
bool exists = count == 0 ? false : true;
return exists;
```

Comment: what about this: bool exists = await _connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<bool>("select count(1) from .. ");  ? @AmitJoshi

Comment: @Sunny: `COUNT(1)` does not count single rows, it counts the number of times the constant `1` occurs in the result set (that is, once per row). It's equivalent to `COUNT(42)` or `COUNT(*)`, although some really naive database engines may choose to implement them differently (for example, not reading actual columns when specifying `COUNT(1)`, even though this isn't required for `COUNT(*)` either).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the next query :

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM employee_master WHERE employee_id = @columnValue)
```